# Linq to SQL records not updating

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get a list of records from a table and then in a `foreach` loop I am trying to `update` the records one by one.

Here is my code

```
     public IEnumerable<MessageOut> GetSMSInformation()
        {
            using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var sms = db.MessageOuts.Where(msg => msg.msgstatus.Equals("Pending")).Select(msg => msg);
                return sms.ToList();
            }
        }



     public void StartSMSSending()
        {
            var information = GetSMSInformation();

            foreach (var sms in information)
            {
                SendSMS(sms.reciever, sms.msg);
                UpdateRecords(sms,"Delivered", DateTime.Now);
            }
        }

   public void UpdateRecords(MessageOut sms, string msgStatus, DateTime sentTime)
        {
            using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                sms.msgstatus = msgStatus;
                sms.senttime = sentTime;
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
```

The records just don't update.I am not getting any errors as well.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to perform an update operation with Linq2Sql classes you need to keep your context alive. In the example you have above, you include your selection inside a using statement, so your records are returned and then the context is dumped. When you go to make the update, there is a fresh context, so there is no change registered to the objects. A way to do this could be to make the context a more global object or to pass it as a parameter.

```
public IEnumerable<MessageOut> GetSMSInformation(DataContext context)
{
    var sms = context.MessageOuts.Where(
        msg => msg.msgstatus.Equals("Pending")).Select(msg => msg);
    return sms.ToList();
}

public void StartSMSSending()
{
    using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        var information = GetSMSInformation(db);

        foreach (var sms in information)
        {
            SendSMS(sms.reciever, sms.msg);
            UpdateRecords(sms,"Delivered", DateTime.Now, db);
        }
    }
}

public void UpdateRecords(MessageOut sms, string msgStatus, DateTime sentTime, DataContext context)
{
    sms.msgstatus = msgStatus;
    sms.senttime = sentTime;
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Or, you could do this (my preferred method):

```
public IEnumerable<MessageOut> GetSMSInformation()
{
    var sms = Context.MessageOuts.Where(
        msg => msg.msgstatus.Equals("Pending")).Select(msg => msg);
    return sms.ToList();
}

public void StartSMSSending()
{
    var information = GetSMSInformation(db);

    foreach (var sms in information)
    {
        SendSMS(sms.reciever, sms.msg);
        UpdateRecords(sms,"Delivered", DateTime.Now, db);
    }
}

public void UpdateRecords(MessageOut sms, string msgStatus, DateTime sentTime)
{
    sms.msgstatus = msgStatus;
    sms.senttime = sentTime;
    Context.SubmitChanges();
}

private DataClasses1DataContext _context = null;
public DataClasses1DataContextContext
{
    get
    {
        return _context ?? (_context = new DataClasses1DataContext());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , understood my mistake.+1 for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You are extracting the data from this DB context:

```
    public IEnumerable<MessageOut> GetSMSInformation()
    {
        using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var sms = db.MessageOuts.Where(msg => msg.msgstatus.Equals("Pending")).Select(msg => msg);
            return sms.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Then you are updating data from the previous DB context are you are submitting changes to a different DB context:

```
    public void UpdateRecords(MessageOut sms, string msgStatus, DateTime sentTime)
    {
        using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            sms.msgstatus = msgStatus;
            sms.senttime = sentTime;
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Pass the DB context as a reference or best **keep is as a member of your class**. This ensures a single db context instance for your class instance.

My suggestion would be the following:

```
class SmsCenter
{
        private DataClasses1DataContext _dbContext;

        public SmsCenter()
        {
            _dbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        }

        public IEnumerable<MessageOut> GetSMSInformation()
        {
            var sms = _dbContext.MessageOuts.Where(msg => msg.msgstatus.Equals("Pending")).Select(msg => msg);
            return sms.ToList();
        }



        public void StartSMSSending()
        {
            var information = GetSMSInformation();

            foreach (var sms in information)
            {
                SendSMS(sms.reciever, sms.msg);
                UpdateRecords(sms,"Delivered", DateTime.Now);
            }
        }

        public void UpdateRecords(MessageOut sms, string msgStatus, DateTime sentTime)
        {
            sms.msgstatus = msgStatus;
            sms.senttime = sentTime;
            _dbContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.Understood what was the mistake.+1 for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you din't relate "sms" object with db, like

```
            sms.msgstatus = msgStatus;
            sms.senttime = sentTime;
            db.MessageOut.Add(sms);
            //or
            db.MessageOut=sms;
            db.SubmitChanges();
```